# Split Java String by New Line

Tags: java, regex, split, newline

I'm trying to split text in a `JTextArea` using a regex to split the String by `\n` However, this does not work and I also tried by `\r\n|\r|n` and many other combination of regexes.
Code:

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    String split[], docStr = null;
    Document textAreaDoc = (Document)e.getDocument();

    try {
        docStr = textAreaDoc.getText(textAreaDoc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), textAreaDoc.getEndPosition().getOffset());
    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    split = docStr.split("\\n");
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you get? Dont say "does not work", that doesnt mean anything. Tell us the error/result you get. 

That is the first step in debugging code - figure out what the wrong result is, and how your program got to that.

Comment: What do you realy want to do?

 - break lines as they are entered in the JTextArea?
 - finding where the JTextArea is doing line wraps?
 - ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079545/1097600 Use string.lines()

Answer (score 863, accepted):

This should cover you:

```
String lines[] = string.split("\\r?\\n");
```

There's only really two newlines (UNIX and Windows) that you need to worry about.

Comment: A JTextArea document SHOULD use only '\n'; its Views completely ignore '\r'.  But if you're going to look for more than one kind of separator, you might as well look for all three: "\r?\n|\r".

Comment: Mac 9 uses \r. OSX 10 uses \n

Comment: ${fn:length(fn:split(data, '\\r?\\n'))} is not working in jstl

Comment: Isn't it: 'String[] lines = String.split("\\r?\\n");' ?

Comment: @antak yes, `split` by default removes trailing empty strings if they ware result of split. To turn this mechanism off you need to use overloaded version of `split(regex, limit)` with negative limit like `text.split("\\r?\\n", -1)`. More info: [Java String split removed empty values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Comment: String[] lines = string.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")); This will work fine while you use strings generated in your same OS/app, but if for example you are running your java application under linux and you retrieve a text from a database that was stored as a windows text, then it could fail.

Comment: The comment by @stivlo is misinformation, and it is unfortunate that it has so many upvotes.  As @ Raekye pointed out, OS X (now known as macOS) has used \n as its line separator since it was released in 2001.  Mac OS 9 was released in 1999, and I have never seen a Mac OS 9 or below machine used in production.  There is not a single modern operating system that uses \r as a line separator. NEVER write code that expects \r to be the line separator on Mac, unless a) you're into retro computing, b) have an OS 9 machine spun up, and c) can reliably determine that the machine is actually OS 9.

Comment: And what does it mean?

Comment: This answer did not work for me. I just use "String pieces[] = text.split("\n") " or "String pieces[] = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")) "on java 8.

Comment: What about unicode??
 A next-line character ('\u0085'),
A line-separator character ('\u2028'), or
A paragraph-separator character ('\u2029).

Comment: how about this: \v+ (one or more vertical whitespace character)

Comment: Are _double_ backslashes necessary?

Answer (score 179):

[`String#split​(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method is using regex (regular expressions). Since Java 8 regex supports `\R` which represents (from [documentation of Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

> **Linebreak matcher**
>   \R         Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to
>   `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

So we can use it to match:

- `\u000D\000A` -> `\r\n` pair
- [\u000A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm) -> line feed (`\n`)
- [\u000B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm) -> line tabulation (DO NOT confuse with [character tabulation `\t` which is `\u0009`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm))
- [\u000C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) -> form feed (`\f`)
- [\u000D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm) -> carriage return (`\r`)
- [\u0085](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm) -> next line (NEL)
- [\u2028](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) -> line separator
- [\u2029](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) -> paragraph separator

As you see `\r\n` is placed at start of regex which ensures that regex will try to match this *pair* first, and only if that match fails it will try to match *single character* line separators.

---

So if you want to split on line separator use `split("\\R")`.

If you [don't want to remove from resulting array trailing empty strings `""`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values) use `split(regex, limit)` with negative `limit` parameter like `split("\\R", -1)`.

If you want to treat one or more continues empty lines as single delimiter use `split("\\R+")`.

Comment: Yes, it's the best answer.  Unfortunate that the question was asked six years too early for this answer.

Comment: I ended up splitting on `\\R+`, to avoid any end-of-line characters that were not covered by `\\R` alone.

Comment: **JAVA 9 PROBLEM with `find` `matches`**. Java 9 incorrectly allows regex like `\R\R` to match sequence `\r\n` which represents *single separation sequence*. To solve such problem we can write regex like `(?>\u000D\u000A)|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]` which thanks to [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>\u000D\u000A)` will prevent regex which already matched `\r\n` to backtrack and try to match `\r` and `\n` separately.

Answer (score 142):

If you don’t want empty lines:

```
String.split("[\\r\\n]+")
```

Comment: double backslashes are unnecessary, see section "Backslashes, escapes, and quoting" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @giulio Yes, I know (see [Understanding regex in Java: split(“\t”) vs split(“\\t”) - when do they both work, and when should they be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762347/understanding-regex-in-java-split-t-vs-split-t-when-do-they-both-wor/3762377#3762377)).

Comment: This worked on Mac OSX when the above answer did not.

Comment: This also worked for me.  Excellent solution.  It worked for the following 2 cases: 1)  i woke up at 3 o clock.\r\n\r\nI hope 2) this is real life\r\nso I

Comment: This answer is exactly correct.  One little suggestion would be that it might be helpful to add _why_ it gets rid of the empty lines for people that might not be as familiar with regex and how it behaves.  For anybody that might be wondering, it's because the "+" is a greedy operator and will match at least one but will continue to match the '\r\n' characters until it no longer can match them.  See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy

Comment: Why not `[\\r?\\n]+`?

Comment: @tresf You can't use quantifiers in square brackets.

Answer (score 65):

```
String.split(System.lineSeparator());
```

This should be system independent

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but you should take care that the text actually uses the system's line separator. I've good many many text files under unix (e.g. XML) that uses "Windows" separators and quite a few under Windows that use unix separators.

Comment: Works even on android

Comment: Files created in a Windows OS and transfered to a Unix OS will still contain \r\n seperators. I think it's better to play safe and take both seperators in account.

Comment: This is a very problematic approach! The file may not originate from the system running the code. I strongly discourage these kinds of "system independent" designs that actually depends on a specific system, the runtime system.

Comment: @Martin if you have control over the deployed system, this is fine. However, if you are deploying your code to the cloud and have no control, then its not the best way to do it

Comment: @Shervin It is never the best way to do it. It is in fact very bad practice. Consider some other programmer calling System.setProperty("line.separator", "you have no point"); Your code is broken. It might even be called similarly by a dependency you have no knowledge about.

Comment: This did not work as the file originated on Unix, and was being split on Windows.

Comment: @Martin -- "some other programmer calling System.setProperty("line.separator", "you have no point"); " --- Just wondering, wouldn't such idiocy/sabotage break a lot of expected behaviours in the JDK libraries, too?

Comment: @Rop I can't think of any cases right away, but there might exist dependencies to system properties that actually break code. I would strongly encourage configuration without use of system properties whenever possible.

Answer (score 29):

A new method `lines` has been introduced to `String` class in [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11), which returns `Stream<String>`

> Returns a stream of substrings extracted from this string partitioned
>   by line terminators.
>
> Line terminators recognized are line feed "\n" (U+000A), carriage
>   return "\r" (U+000D) and a carriage return followed immediately by a
>   line feed "\r\n" (U+000D U+000A).

Here are a few examples:

```
jshell> "lorem \n ipusm \n sit".lines().forEach(System.out::println)
lorem
 ipusm
 sit

jshell> "lorem \n ipusm \r  sit".lines().forEach(System.out::println)
lorem
 ipusm
  sit

jshell> "lorem \n ipusm \r\n  sit".lines().forEach(System.out::println)
lorem
 ipusm
  sit
```

[String#lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lines())

Comment: Why is there no such method on Android...

Answer (score 21):

In `JDK11` the `String` class has a `lines()` method:

> Returning a stream of lines extracted from this string, separated by
>   line terminators.

Further, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lines()) goes on to say:

> A line terminator is one of the following: a line feed character "\n"
>   (U+000A), a carriage return character "\r" (U+000D), or a carriage
>   return followed immediately by a line feed "\r\n" (U+000D U+000A). A
>   line is either a sequence of zero or more characters followed by a
>   line terminator, or it is a sequence of one or more characters
>   followed by the end of the string. A line does not include the line
>   terminator.

With this one can simply do:

```
Stream<String> stream = str.lines();
```

then if you want an array:

```
String[] array = str.lines().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Given this method returns a Stream it upon up a lot of options for you as it enables one to write *concise* and declarative expression of possibly-parallel operations.

Comment: this works for java8  and splits the string into a stream of line strings: Arrays.stream(str.split("\\n"))

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to double escape characters in character groups.

For all non empty lines use:

```
String.split("[\r\n]+")
```

Comment: Yes, you do.  If they need double-escaping anywhere, they need it everywhere.  Whitespace escapes like `\r` and `\n` can have one or two backslashes; they work either way.

Comment: The double backslash `'\\'` in code becomes a `'\'` character and is then passed to the RegEx engine, so `"[\\r\\n]"` in code becomes `[\r\n]` in memory and RegEx will process that. I don't know how exactly Java handles RegEx, but it is a good practice to pass a "pure" ASCII string pattern to the RegEx engine and let it process rather than passing binary characters. `"[\r\n]"` becomes (hex) `0D0A` in memory and one RegEx engine might accept it while another will choke. So the bottom line is that even if Java's flavour of RegEx doesn't need them, keep double slashes for compatibility

Answer (score 10):

All answers given here actually do not respect Javas definition of new lines as given in e.g. BufferedReader#readline. Java is accepting `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n` as new line. Some of the answers match multiple empty lines or malformed files. E..g. `<sometext>\n\r\n<someothertext>` when using `[\r\n]+`would result in two lines.

```
String lines[] = string.split("(\r\n|\r|\n)", -1);
```

In contrast, the answer above has the following properties:

- it complies with Javas definition of a new line such as e.g. the BufferedReader is using it
- it does not match multiple new lines
- it does not remove trailing empty lines

Answer (score 9):

If, for some reason, you don't want to use `String.split` (for example, because of [regular expressions](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)) and you want to use functional programming on Java 8 or newer:

```
List<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(string))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I know this may be an overkill solution.

Comment: Or `String[] lines = new BufferedReader(...).lines().toArray(String[]::new);` for an array instead of a list. The nice thing about this solution is that `BufferedReader` knows about all kinds of like terminators, so it can handle text in all sorts of formats. (Most of the regex-based solutions posted here fall short in this regard.)

Comment: This solution is obsolete since Java 11 and the introduction of the String.lines() method.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this would work:

Remove the double backslashes from the parameter of the split method:

```
split = docStr.split("\n");
```

Comment: Not really. When you write a regex in the form of a Java String literal, you can use "\n" to pass the regex compiler a linefeed symbol, or "\\n" to pass it the escape sequence for a linefeed. The same goes for all the other whitespace escapes except \v, which isn't supported in Java literals.

Comment: @Yuval. Sorry that is incorrect, you don't need it at all "Backslashes, escapes, and quoting" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: not sure if it worked with previous versions of Java. But it'll not work anymore. the `split()` method expects a regex and the valid regex would be `\\\\n`

Answer (score 5):

For preserving empty lines from getting squashed use:

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n", -1);
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answers did not help me on Android, thanks to the [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068483/10807406) response that worked for me on Android. I will leave some of [Pshemo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068483/10807406) here :

```
split("\\\\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, Java lacks a both simple and efficient method for splitting a string by a fixed string. Both `String::split` and the stream API are complex and relatively slow. Also, they can produce different results.

`String::split` examines its input, then compiles to `java.util.regex.Pattern` every time (except if the input contains only a single char that's safe).

However, `Pattern` is very fast, *once it was compiled*. So the best solution is to precompile the pattern:

```java
private static final Pattern LINE_SEP_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\R");
```

Then use it like this:

```java
String[] lines = LINE_SEP_PATTERN.split(input);
```

From Java 8, `\R` matches to any line break specified by Unicode. Prior to Java 8 you could use something like this:

```java
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(System.lineSeparator()))
```

Answer (score 3):

The above code doesnt actually do anything visible - it just calcualtes then dumps the calculation. Is it the code you used, or just an example for this question?

try doing textAreaDoc.insertString(int, String, AttributeSet) at the end?

Comment: insertUpdate() is a DocumentListener method. Assuming the OP is using it right, trying to modify the document from within the listener method will generate an exception. But you're right: the code in that question doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 3):

There is new boy in the town, so you need not to deal with all above complexities.
**From JDK 11 onward**, just need to write as single line of code, it will split lines and returns you Stream of String.

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Stream<String> lines="foo \n bar \n baz".lines();
   //Do whatever you want to do with lines
}}
```

Some references.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lines()
https://www.azul.com/90-new-features-and-apis-in-jdk-11/

I hope this will be helpful to someone. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

`String lines[] =String.split( System.lineSeparator())`

Answer (score 2):

After failed attempts on the basis of all given solutions. I replace `\n` with some special word and then split. For me following did the trick:

```
article = "Alice phoned\n bob.";
article = article.replace("\\n", " NEWLINE ");
String sen [] = article.split(" NEWLINE ");
```

I couldn't replicate the example given in the question. But, I guess this logic can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the previous answers, guava's `Splitter` API can be used if other operations are to be applied to the resulting lines, like trimming lines or filtering empty lines :

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

Iterable<String> split = Splitter.onPattern("\r?\n").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(docStr);
```

Note that the result is an `Iterable` and not an array.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different conventions (it could be said that those are *de facto* standards) to set and display a line break:

- `carriage return` + `line feed`
- `line feed`
- `carriage return`

In some text editors, it is possible to exchange one for the other:

[image: Notepad++]

The simplest thing is to normalize to `line feed`and then split.

```
final String[] lines = contents.replace("\r\n", "\n")
                               .replace("\r", "\n")
                               .split("\n", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

- try this hope it was helpful for you

---

```
 String split[], docStr = null;
Document textAreaDoc = (Document)e.getDocument();

try {
    docStr = textAreaDoc.getText(textAreaDoc.getStartPosition().getOffset(), textAreaDoc.getEndPosition().getOffset());
} catch (BadLocationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

split = docStr.split("\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package in.javadomain;

public class JavaSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "chennai\nvellore\ncoimbatore\nbangalore\narcot";
        System.out.println("Before split:\n");
        System.out.println(input);

        String[] inputSplitNewLine = input.split("\\n");
        System.out.println("\n After split:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<inputSplitNewLine.length; i++){
            System.out.println(inputSplitNewLine[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This pales in comparison to the other answers, which are more explanatory and less code-heavy.  Could you explain what it is you're accomplishing with this code, and why it would make a suitable answer?

Comment: This has nothing to do with splitting a file into lines. Consider removing your answer.