# Split string into matrix array

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, matrix

I have a String:

```
1,3,4,5,
1,4,5,0,
2,5,3,8,
```

That I want to store in a variable matrix (`int[][]`). What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I use the `String` class' methods? Or should I use a `Regex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First (by `String.split(..)`) [split on newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line), then split the items of each of the resultant array on `,`. Then parse each using `Integer.parseInt(..)`

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = "1,3,4,5,\n1,4,5,0,\n2,5,3,8,";

String[] str1 = input.split("\n");
int[][] matrix = new int[str1.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    String[] str2 = str1[i].split(",");
    matrix[i] = new int[str2.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(str2[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is de-facto deprecated: "It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Hmm that's interesting that the JavaDoc actually recommends that now, didn't realize that. It seems like it's best to avoid regex where possible though. As well StringTokenizer is 3 times faster in this case (10k iterations) and does less object creation, although likely doesn't matter.

Comment: Replaced `StringTokenizer` with `String.split()` as suggested.