# SPLIT with \n Delimiter

Tags: java, android

I need to split string with delimiter of `\n` when I use this code:

```
String delimiter = "\n";
String[] temp;
temp = description2[position].split(delimiter);
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    holder.weeklyparty_text3.setSingleLine(false);
    holder.weeklyparty_text3.setText(temp[i]);
}
```

but not get split string from `\n`.

Comment: I never did this, but I would suggest, try String delimiter = "\\n";

Comment: i have tried it but still not get O/P

Comment: What is the input and what is output you are expecting?

Comment: 01-26 02:24:32.611: INFO/System.out(418):\nAspen Social Club\nBar Basque\nCrimson\nForum\nLexicon\n

Comment: String tempStr = "\nAspen Social Club\nBar Basque\nCrimson\nForum\nLexicon\n";
        String[] splitArr = tempStr.split("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<splitArr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Split size is: "+splitArr[i]);
        }

Comment: and I got this Output:  Split value is: 
Split value is: Aspen Social Club
Split value is: Bar Basque
Split value is: Crimson
Split value is: Forum
Split value is: Lexicon

Comment: but now another problem are raise

Comment: when i have split from \n into array i got correct array but when i set to textview it show only last position item.

Comment: Please post new question, with updated code and new issue. We can't extended discussion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split uses regex - so to split on a newline, you should use:

```
String delimiter = "\\n";
```

Comment: Post the code that you are using to populate the description2 string array.  If you are using a read line method, for instance, the \n might not be in your data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash in the delimiter string: `"\\n"`

Answer (score 0):

In order to support Unix and Windows new lines use:

String lines[] = String.split("\r?\n");

as described in:

[Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)