# Converting a String with Breaks to an Arraylist

Tags: java

If I have the following string:

```
String string = "My \n name \n is \n John \n Doe";
```

And I want to separate each word and add it to an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How would I do that?

Bare in mind that the line break may not be \n - it could be anything.

Thanks

Comment: [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: This question was actually better answered in the following thread: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\n");

for(String line: lines) {
    sentence.add(line);
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Use `Arrays.asList()`

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s+"));
```

- you are splitting on "any number of whitepsace symbols", which includes space, new line, etc
- the returned list is readonly. If you need a new, writable list, use the copy-constructor
  `new ArrayList(list)`

Comment: I *think* the OP wants his string breaked according to lines, not white spaces.

Comment: \s includes new lines. And I interpreted his last sentence as it can be any other whitespace. Though I might be wrong

Comment: but it also includes white spaces, what will `"My name is \n amit"` yield?

Comment: I just updated my comment. The thing is, he wants to separate "words". So I assumed he needs any whitespace. Let's see if my assumption is correct

Comment: Well then - if this is indeed the case, the answer fits.

Comment: I'd prefer to only split by line breaks because there might be more than one word before the next line break.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.split("\\s*\n\\s*")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to get a `String[]`, and then use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). It will get a `List<String>`, if you want an `ArrayList` you can use the constructor [`ArrayList(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
String string = "My \n name \n is \n John \n Doe";
String[] arr = string.split("\\s*\n\\s*");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

You can also use [`Character.LINE_SEPARATOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#LINE_SEPARATOR) instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List < String > arrayList = Arrays.asList( "My \n name \n is \n John \n Doe".split( "\\n" ) );
        // Removes the 2 white spaces: .split( " \\n " )
    }
}
```