# newline - not added or unable to split by newline

Tags: java, android

I am reading android. So, It is just for practice.

```
String storedData = readData();
String lines[] = storedData.split("\\n");

int linesLength = lines.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < linesLength; i++) {
            tmp = "it is me " + tmp + lines[i] + "\r\n";//i have assigned all the variables.
        }
textbox.setText(tmp);
```

Everything is displayed in single line.

```
String lines[] = storedData.split("\\n"); 
String lines[] = storedData.split("\r\n"); 
String lines[] = storedData.split("\\r?\\n");
String lines[] = storedData.split("\n");
```

Tried all the above. Not working for me.

This is how i have written the text in a file.
Am i writing the new content in the storedData with newline? Is that correct?
I assume storedData has a newline in the end. So i join the content and add a newline in the end.

```
content = storedData + content + "\n";
outputStream = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

it is always displaying the output in single line.

```
textbox.setText(tmp);
it is me test test1 test2
```

in the below line,

```
content = storedData + content + "\n";
//content = a word received from EditText
//storedData = content read from a stored file.
```

Comment: Have you just tried with  `split("\n");`  ??

Comment: And check once this:link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Comment: Can you please update the post with the string `storedData`,So that we can see what exactly coming in that.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ `storedData` is some string received from the file. I have written the code which stores the data on the file. That data is `storedData`

Comment: you can put a break point there or put `sysout`  to see the console. I'm suspecting  that some special chars or some weird lines causing the issue.

Comment: As define tmp result shoult not be `it is me test test1 test2`.

Comment: The loop is executed only once. That is why the output is in the single line. I will update the code. You will understand it now

Comment: @Kamini *imo* It is not problem with the loop,Split has not returned the expected `array` of result.

Comment: yes, data are not stored line by line. That should be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
String lines[] = storedData.split("\\n");
```

with

```
String lines[] = storedData.split("\n");
```

Actually your `lines[]` is containing only one line no splits occurs. try that.

Comment: do `Sysout(storedData)`, verify what you actually writtent in the file. If problem is there the you need to change there.

Comment: it is android app. how can i do that? just entering will give the output? `The method Sysout(String) is undefined for the type DisplayActivity` i tried to put it `textbox.setSet(Sysout(storedData));`

Comment: No, i have asked you to put `System.out.print(storedData)` in your code, which will help you to get content of storedData. you have to check the `System.out.print data` from **LogCat**.

Comment: @PrabhaVathi I agree that,It's a weird problem, but how about putting a breakpoints and watching there ?

Comment: I can't find any output in LogCat. I tried all verbose, error, info.. By the way, If i change like this, `content = storedData + content + "::";` and `storedData.split("::");` I am getting the complete array and loop works good. does it give any idea?

Comment: Ok, it's not a problem. you can find that By doing a serch by keyword `System.out`.