# How to Split string in java using "\n"

Tags: java, string

I am taking a command line input string like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String line = br.readLine();
```

I want to split this string which is:

```
String line = "int t; //variable t  
t->a = 0; //t->a does something  
return 0;"
```

like this:

```
String[] arr = line.split("\n");  
arr[0] = "int t; //variable t";  
arr[1] = "t->a=0; //t->a does something";  
arr[2] = "return 0";
```

but when i run my java program that split function only returns this:

> `arr[0] = "int t; //variable t";`

it didn't returns other two strings that i mentioned above,why this is happening please explain.

Comment: Are you sure there are `"\n"` in the `String`? This works fine for me. Print the string `line`, and tell us if the output is shown in 3 lines.

Comment: Just because you have made a line break in your code, it doesn't mean that there is a real line break in your string.

Comment: arr[0] contains the expected value. What does arr[1] contain?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/Jm3MZ7 Please double check your input

Comment: And beware for the future: String#split(String) takes a regex string, not a plain string.

Comment: @Christian,@RC i am taking input from command line here is my code:  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String line = br.readLine(); when i print String line it gives only this int t; //variable t

Comment: @abhishek92 `br.readLine()` takes the input line by line. of course you only got `"int t; //variable t"` because that was the only current value of `line`. you have nothing to split by `("\n")`

Comment: read line by line, join then split? something is wrong here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Java String by New Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Answer (score 5):

The method `readLine()` will read the input **until a new-line character is entered**. That new-line character is `"\n"`. Therefore, it won't ever read the `String` separated by `"\n"`.

**One solution:**

You can read the lines with a `while` loop and store them in an `ArrayList`:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }

    for (String s : lines) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

To stop the `while` you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> in UNIX, if I'm not wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This should work!Also make sure if your input contains `\n`

```
 String[] arr = line.split("\r?\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment you seem to take the input like this

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here the `line` represents ***already split*** string by `\n`. When you hit enter on the console, the text entered in one line gets captured into `line`. As per me you are reading line,  ***only once*** which captures just `int t;//variable t`, where there is nothing to split.