# Split string by new line symbol

Tags: java, string, split, newline

I'm trying to split lines in this file [eng-pol.txt](http://eng-pol.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/dictionary/stardict/eng-pol.txt) by new line symbol "\n" and it's simply not working... I've tried:

```
String[] words = strLine.split("\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
[abbot    abbot [ˈæbət] <N>\n opat]

String[] words = strLine.split("\\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
[abbot    abbot [ˈæbət] <N>\n opat]

String[] words = strLine.split("\\r|\r");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
[abbot    abbot [ˈæbət] <N>\n opat]
```

Even this:

```
String[] words = strLine.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
[abbot    abbot [ˈæbət] <N>\n opat]
```

I'm reading the file using `BufferedReader` and `readLine` method.

Comment: But it's not. I've tried all the solutions from there and none of them is working

Comment: String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n"); did you try this?

Comment: Yes. The result is the same...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I see that your file contains `\n` literals (not actual line breaks). If you want to split on them then you need to write split as

```
split("\\\\n")
```

Regex which represents `\` literal looks like `\\` (it needs to be escaped, otherwise single `\` will be treated for example as start of predefined character class like `\d` which represents digits).

But String which will represents such regex `\\` need to be written as `"\\\\"` because in string `\` is also special and it also needs to be escaped.

In short to match `\` with regex you need to escape it in two levels:

- in regex `\\`
- in String `"\\\\"`.

Comment: That solution finally worked :) Thaks!

Comment: @Pshemo if you have time can you explain why this works?