# replaceAll () function Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, replaceall

I want to replace the \n character with a space. The below code in not working. Any suggestions?

```
System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=sc.nextLine().toString();
    //String str="one\ntwo";
    if(str.contains("\\n")){
        System.out.println("yes");
        str=str.replaceAll("\\n", " " );
    }
    System.out.println("str : "+str);
```

The input string is one\ntwo

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace \n and \r\n with <br /> in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056834/replace-n-and-r-n-with-br-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
str=str.replaceAll("\\\\n", " " );
```

OR

```
 str=str.replace("\\n", " " );
```

Answer (score 3):

`replaceAll("\\n", " " )` uses regex as first argument and `"\\n"` is treated by Java regex engine as `\n` which represents line separator, not `\` and `n` characters. If you want to replace `\n` literal (two characters) you either need to

- [escape `\` in regex itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068425/split-string-by-new-line-symbol/25068483#25068483) by `replaceAll("\\\\n", " " );`
- use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` which will do escaping for you

Preferred way is using

```
str = str.replace("\\n", " " );
```

---

BTW `sc.nextLine()` already returns String, so there is no need for

```
sc.nextLine().toString();
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^ this part is unnecessary
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not good

```
if(str.contains("\\n")) -> if(str.contains("\n"))
```

all it describe here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5518515/4017037

Comment: It seems that OP doesn't have `\n` (line separator) in String, but `"\\n"` ``\`` character followed by `n`.