# Can I negate the dot?

Tags: java, regex

The following regular expression matches the character a:

```
"a"
```

The following regular expression matches all characters except a:

```
"[^a]"
```

The following regular expression matches a ton of characters:

```
"."
```

How do I match everything that is not matched by `"."`? I can't use the same technique as above:

```
"[^.]"
```

because inside the brackets, the `.` changes meaning and only stands for the character `.` itself :(

Comment: The only things that `.` doesn't match is _possibly_ line terminators, which you can include with `DOTALL`. Is this behavior you really need?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I don't think that's what Fred's trying to do.

Comment: @DonRoby - this is why I should stay out of [regex] questions ;)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was curious if there was a simpler way to answer [question 454908](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/) with something like `"[^.]"`

Comment: . matches any character, so the negation of that would be "don't match any character"? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yep, How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"[^\\.]"
```

use double backslash for regex used character. for example

```
\\.\\]\\[\\-\\)\\(\\?
```

Comment: may i know what your regex does actually?

Comment: match any character except dot.

Answer (score 3):

The below negative lookahead will work.

```
(?:(?!.)[\S\s])
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?:(?!.)[\\S\\s])"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sD9zK6/2)

The idea behind the above regex is, it would match only `\r` or `\n` or `\t` or `\f` that is the characters which aren't matched by a dot (*Multiline mode*).

Comment: Match the character from the list `\S` or `\s` if it's not matched by a dot. So it will end up with  `\r` or `\n` or `\t` or `\f`