# Why doesn't Pattern.MULTILINE match new lines in java regex

Tags: java, regex, multiline

`enter code here`I don't understand how to capture multiple lines with simple regex:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^.*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
matcher = pattern
        .matcher("11-41 pm, Oct 20, 2014 - Stef G: Ik zal er ook zij \n ttrrttttkkk");

matcher.find();
System.out.println("group=" + matcher.group());
```

It outputs:

```
group=11-41 pm, Oct 20, 2014 - Stef G: Ik zal er ook zij
```

In output, text after carrage return is missing.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Because the multiline option doesn't take in account newlines.

Comment: I also tried DOTALL and it doesn't help too

Comment: Can you say what I need to capture new lines

Comment: "When in MULTILINE mode **$ matches just before a line terminator** or the end of the input sequence." Can you simply remove the $ and allow it to greedily match everything?

Comment: No vks. It's my fault. With DOTALL option I can match new lines by a dot `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOTALL option should definitely work for you:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^.*$", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

But if it doesn't for some reason you can specify the option in the actual expression like so:

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(?s)^.*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main reson of this is that you're using the `$` symbol in your regex, as it states for an end of a string or, if multiline enabled, for an end of a line. So you simply find the text from the start of a string till the first end of a line in matching text.

I think that the regex in a form of `^.*$` isn't useful at all. What are you trying to achieve? Select whole text - so use `.*`. If you want to get some text from second line, try to do this:

```
^.*$.*$
```

Or try to get your text being [splitted by newline char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454913/213550):

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");
```