# String.split method to split a string by dot and save it as arraylist

Tags: android, string, arraylist

Am Fetching few lines from remote server and saving each line as an arraylist element by setting dot as a separator. Everything works fine. I just don't understand why a strange `rn` value gets appended to every new line.

E.g.:

> I am going to School. I am feeling hungry

gets split and displayed as

> I am going to School
>
> **rn**I am feeling hungry

What does that `rn` stands for?

I am using `String.split` to separate. My code is below.

```
List<String> po= new ArrayList<String>();

separated_q = Arrays.asList(prdesc.split(Pattern.quote(".")));

for(int k=0;k<separated_q.size();k++) {
    po.add(separated_q.get(k));
}
```

Please help me point out where am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you are only splitting on the period, so if your text is:

```
I am going to School.
I am feeling hungry
```

the program sees this (especially on Windows):

```
I am going to School.\r\nI am feeling hungry
```

The \r is the carriage return character 0x0D and the \n is the linefeed character 0x0A. The `split()` isn't going to change anything with those characters, so you end up with

```
string[0] = "I am going to School"
string[1] = "\r\nI am feeling hungry"
```

You should probably be splitting on the line break itself, rather that the period.  To do that, you would code this:

```
separated_q = Arrays.asList(prdesc.split("\\r?\\n"));
```

That should also get rid of the "\r\n" you are seeing.

See [Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Comment: can you please edit my codes as per your suggestion coz by using trim nothing seems to change. still rn gets displayed

Comment: Let's back up a little bit. "Saving each line by adding the dot as a separator"... How are you doing that?  You should just be able to split on the newline so you don't need to add the dot.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Comment: po.add(separated_q.get(k)); is how I save each line

Comment: I'm talking about the step even before that.  This is data coming from a server, so you must have some code that reads the server data.  Also I have concerns about splitting on the period, because by definition a line is a set of characters between linefeeds, or between a linefeed and the beginning/end of the document.  What happens if there's a dot in the middle of the line?

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "I love writing code. It is so much fun!";

String[] split = myString.split(".");

String sentenceOne = split[0];
String sentenceTwo = split[1];
```

Comment: No, it's not going to display anything. But I can guarantee the values of sentenceOne and sentenceTwo Are the two sentences. Its up to you to display them.