# Split string with blankline

Tags: java, swing

I pull string from textarea by `.gettext()` and it have a blankline.

```
test1111  

test222
```

I need to split this String and keep into array, then `array[0]=test1111` 
`array[1]=test222`

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
String[] lines = text.split("\\s*\\n+\\s*");
```

Or better if you're using Java 8 (per Pshemo), use `"\\R+"`

This will skip over multiple blank lines, or lines filled with white space, and should trim leading and ending whitespace as well.

Comment: Or to split on one or more line separators since Java 8 we can use `"\\R+"` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125/1393766

Comment: @Pshemo: If you don't mind, I'll add this to my community wiki.

Comment: No problem. Added link in earlier comment to one of my answers which explains `\R` a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] lines = jtextFieldName_you_used.getText().split("\\n");
```

It is to store textarea elements to array.Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String str = abc.getText();
for (String retval: str.split(" ")){ System.out.println(retval); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your task right:

```
final String[] lines = data.split("\\n");
final String results[] = new String[lines.length];
int offset = 0;

for (String line : lines) {
   results[offset] = line.split("\\s")[1];
   offset++;
}
```

results:

```
test1111
blankline
test222
```

p.s: without data checks