# Find and replace whole line based on regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have this string

```
Chest pain\tab \tab 72%\tab 0%\tab 67%
 }d \ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\tx10800\tx11520\tx12240\tx12960\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\insrsid14762702 
 }d \ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702 Waveform}{\insrsid14762702 
 }{\insrsid14762702 {\*\shppict{\pict{\*\picprop\shplid1025{\sp{\sn shapeType}{\sv 75}}{\sp{\sn fFlipH}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fFlipV}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fLine}{\sv 0}}{\sp{\sn fLayoutInCell}{\sv 1}}}
\
```

I want to get rid of all lines with `}d \ql` in them

I have tried

```
String v= u.replace("}d \\ql(\\.*)","");
```

but it doesn't detect the line. Having tested it out the culprit must be the .* part but I don't know how to put it in the string.replace

Comment: Do they start with }d \\ql or is it anywhere in the line?

Comment: Why do you have a backslash before the `.*`? What happens if you try `String v= u.replace("}d \\ql.*","");`?

Comment: Usually one space before the } Mark B- that doesn't make a difference I have tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` doesn't use regex syntax, `replaceAll` does. This means that `\\.*` simply replace text which represents `\` `.` and `*`.

So your first solution could look like (notice that to create `\` literal in regex you need to escaped it twice: once in regex `\\` and once in string literal `"\\\\"`)

```
String v = u.replaceAll("\\}d \\\\ql.*","");
```

But possible problem here is that we don't require `\}` to be placed at start of string. Also we are skipping leading space in that line which exist right before `\}`.
To solve it we can add `^\s*` at start of your regex and make `^` represent start of line (we can do it with MULTILINE flag - we can use `(?m)` for that).

So now our solution could look like:

```
String v= u.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*\\}d \\\\ql.*","");
```

But there is another problem. `.` can't match line separators so `.*` will not include them in match which will prevent us from removing them.
So we should include them in our match explicitly (we should also make them optional - we can use `?` quantifier for that - in case line you want to match will be last one, which means it will not have line separator after it). Since Java 8 we can do it with [`\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125/1393766) which can match few line separators (including paragraph separators), or if you want to limit yourself only to `\r` `\n` (or can't use Java 8) you can use something like `(\r?\n|\r)`.

So our ***final*** solution can look like:

in Java 8

```
String v = u.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*\\}d \\\\ql.*\\R?","");
```

pre Java 8

```
String v = u.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*\\}d \\\\ql.*(\r?\n|\r)?","");
```

Comment: Final `\R`/`[\r\n]` are better quantified with `*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I though about it but I am not sure if OP also want to remove following empty lines so I didn't add any repetitions for line separators.

Comment: Then, in order not to remove empty lines, `?` is better. Maybe not required in this case, sure, but is a good idea in general.

Comment: or both versions: `String v = u.replaceAll("(?m)^\\s*\\}d \\\\ql.*$\s*^?","");`