# Replace every linebreak with another symbol

Tags: java

i'm creating a little programm atm and i need to replace every linebreak with a symbol, f.e. "#".
So if i enter this text:

```
test1 
test2
test3
```

it should become

```
test1#test2#test3
```

i tried doing this:

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("\n", "#"); //text is the inputed text
```

after some research i also tried

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\\\n", "#");
```

because somebody says this has something to do with the compiler or idk. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And how are you getting `text`? Does it, in fact, contain line-breaks? Also, `replace` is what you want; `replaceAll` takes a *regular expression*.

Comment: text is a string variable and i get the text from a jTextPane like this: textPane.getText() @CubeJockey

Answer (score 3):

Linebreaks are system dependent. On UNIX systems, it is "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it is "\r\n" . So it is better to make your code platform independent.

Use something like :

```
String text = rawText.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "#");
```

Pleas note that System.lineSeparator() is available from Java 1.7.

Comment: Additionally if you are not going to use regex syntax then you can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. Both method will replace *all* occurrences of searched text (main difference between them is only regex syntax support).

Answer (score 0):

Use an escaped backslash by typing `\\`. Also check for carriage returns `\r\n`.

```
String test = "test1\ntest2\r\ntest3";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(\\n|\\r\\n)", "#"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll("\n", "#")` should work fine if your lines ware separated only by `\n`. If it didn't work then it means your text is using other line separator like `\r`, `\u0085` (next line - NEL) or most probably combination of `\r\n`.

Since `replaceAll` is using regex syntax, to match all line separators we can use [`\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125/1393766) (added to regex engine in Java 8). So you could try with.

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("\\R", "#");
```

If you can't use Java 8 (like in case of Android applications) you could use regex which will represent `\r\n` or `\n` or `\r`:

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("\r\n|\n|\r", "#");
//can be reduced to .replaceAll("\r?\n|\r", "#");
```