# How to split a java string based on newline character

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string in java defined as below:

```
String numbers = null;
for (int i= 0; i < contactNumberList.size();i++)
{
    numbers = contactNumberList.get(i) + "\n" + numbers;
}
```

where contactNumberList contains four items as : 9891, 3432, 5432, 9890.
So after the loop i have **numbers string** as:
**9890\n5432\n3432\n9891\nnull**

Then i passed the above string through following APIs.

```
String toUnicodeEncoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(numbers);
toUnicodeEncoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(toUnicodeEncoded);
```

Now when i try to print the string toUnicodeEncoded character by character as below:

```
for (int i =0;i<toUnicodeEncoded.length();i++)
{
   Logger.log("chat at  "+i + " = "+(toUnicodeEncoded.charAt(i)));
}
```

It gives :

```
char at 0 = 9
char at 1 = 8
char at 2 = 9
char at 3 = 0
char at 4 = \
char at 5 = n
```

and so on .

My point is "\n" became two characters \  and n .
    Now i wanted to split the **string toUnicodeEncoded** based on "\n" using the following APIs:

```
String lines[] = toUnicodeEncoded.split("\\n");
```

But its not able to split it because now "\n" has become \ and n. How do i split toUnicodeEncoded string by "\n" or new line character.

BAsically i want the output as :

```
9890
5432
3432
9891
null
```

i.e all four numbers . How do i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for replying. But i got it working using following approach:

```
String pattern = Pattern.quote("\\" + "n");
String lines[] = toUnicodeEncoded.split(pattern);
```

Comment: This is because your original attempt `toUnicodeEncoded.split("\\n");` was passing the backslash to a *regex* (read the Javadoc for `String.split`) and the regex treats the backslash with a special meaning. What you needed to do was to give the regex an escaped backslash: `toUnicodeEncoded.split("\\\\n");`.

Answer (score 4):

When we split your string with \n it is giving expected output. But it is better to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`

```
String s="9890\n5432\n3432\n9891\nnull";
s = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(s);
s= StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(s);

for (String number:s.split("\n")) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

**result**

```
9890
5432
3432
9891
null
```

Comment: Using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is problematic if you have a file on a Unix system that has Windows line endings. Better to use `.split("\\R")` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125/3059685.

Answer (score 2):

use this, should do the trick

```
String.split("[\\r\\n]+")
```