# Can't seem to split String by new line regex

Tags: java, regex, string, newline, bukkit

I have this method, and it will not correctly add the split string to my list.

```
public static List<String> formatConfigMessages(FileConfiguration config, String key, boolean colour, Object... regex) {
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    if (config.isList(key)) {
        config.getStringList(key).forEach(message -> {
            if (message.contains("\\n")) {
                Collections.addAll(messages, message.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r"));
            } else {
                messages.add(message);
            }
        });
    } else {
        String message = config.getString(key);
        if (message.contains("\\n")) {
            Collections.addAll(messages, message.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r"));
        } else {
            messages.add(message);
        }
    }
    return messages.stream().map(message -> formatMessage(message, colour, regex)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

For a bit of context, this method is used to format configurable messages for my [SpigotMC](http://spigotmc.org) plugin. The method takes 4 parameters:

1. FileConfiguration - A class made to simplify the use of YAML configuration files.
2. String - the key of the message (can be indexed with '.', either side of the '.' represents a different level of the YAML file).
3. Boolean - whether or not reserved characters in the string should be converted into coloured characters (colours can only be seen by the client)
4. Object... - some patterns, etc.) <name> to be replaced with the following value in the array.

That is the chunk of code that won't work. Initially, I attempted to set the regex as `\n`, but that didn't return a list. I assumed this was because it was searching for already parsed new lines rather than the '\n' stream of characters. So I changed my regex to \n, which still didn't work. I search the internet and found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line) that I should use the regex `\\r\\n` as well as `\\n` because `\r` is used on Windows systems. This again did not work, and I keep getting 1 string with the \n still inside.

Comment: Do you have newline symbols at all or 2-char combinations of ``\`` + `n`? Also, to match any line break, you may use `\R` - `.split("\\R+")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you mean by newline symbols? Anyway, I'm using the '\n' combination. However, I'm making this for a client and I want it to work with any newline value they use.

Comment: A newline symbol is a decimal `10` char. Google ASCII table. In a Java string literal, `"\n"` defines a newline. A `"\\n"` defines two char sequence, ``\`` and `n`.

Comment: Okay. Did my comment give you what you need?

Comment: I think  I should ask you this question. Did `.split("\\R+")` work? If not, there are no literal line breaks in your input.

Comment: Nope. Produces same results

Comment: Good, so there are no line breaks in the input. You cannot split with something that does not exist.

Comment: Hold on. My last comment was referring to the unedited version of your previous comment. I am using line breaks in this format "<text> \n <text>"

Comment: I think he was clarifying whether the text literally contains "\n" or if it actually has a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why.

Regex has its own escape sequences, denoted with `\\` (the escape sequence for `\`), since Java reserves `\`.

For example, `\\w` denotes any character in a word.

To split by "\n", you'll need `\\\\n` instead, because `\\n` in regex represents an actual line break, just as `\n` represents one in Java.

Example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello\\nworld".split("\\\\n")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello world\nwith newline".split("\\n")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("Hello world\nwith newline".split("\n")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("I won't\\nsplit".split("\\n")));
```

Prints:

```
[Hello, world]
[Hello world, with newline]
[Hello world, with newline] <-- Same effect as above
[I won't\nsplit]
```

[Additionally, to handle all three line end types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454913/7366707) (though `\r` on its own is uncommon nowadays), use the regex `\\\\r?\\\\n|\\\\r` instead.