# Java splitting string into paragraphs

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I have a big string that needs to be split into paragraphs based on "-- " in a single line and below is the string

```
access.log-2017-07-10   05:30:02    127.0.0.1   GET 200 58944   0.079   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /platform/scheduler/logout.jsp  9148257800613007309 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
access.log-2017-07-10   05:45:00    127.0.0.1   POST    200 10  0.084   "55"    ""  -   -   -   -   -   /platform/scheduler/login.jsp   9148257800613007349 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
access.log-2017-07-10   05:45:00    127.0.0.1   GET 302 333 0.02    -   "test123"   -   -   -   -   -   /report/scheduler/schedule.jsp?notify=y 9148257800613007349 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
access.log-2017-07-10   05:45:00    127.0.0.1   GET 200 168427  0.171   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /report/reports.jsp?report=6030654077013281451  9148257800613007349 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
access.log-2017-07-10   05:45:00    127.0.0.1   GET 200 58944   0.034   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /platform/scheduler/logout.jsp  9148257800613007349 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
access.log:2017-07-10   05:59:05    10.233.32.75    POST    302 325 3.189   "133"   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /login.jsp  9148257800613007357 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   "http://10.112.251.31:6300/login.jsp?redirectKey=_from_url_e4600ddc-2c02-4c85-9eff-83bee5457c14" kranthi123
access.log-2017-07-10   05:59:06    10.233.32.75    GET 200 30119   1.422   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /ncobject.jsp?id=9137288153213290331    9148257800613007357 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   "http://10.112.251.31:6300/login.jsp?redirectKey=_from_url_e4600ddc-2c02-4c85-9eff-83bee5457c14"
access.log-2017-07-10   05:59:07    10.233.32.75    GET 200 32  0.009   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /CSServlet  9148257800613007357 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   "http://10.112.251.31:6300/ncobject.jsp?id=9137288153213290331"
access.log-2017-07-10   05:59:07    10.233.32.75    GET 404 52534   0.454   -   ""  -   -   -   -   -   /scripts/jquery/form-styler/jquery/jquery.formstyler/jquery.formstyler.min.js   9148257800613007357 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   "http://10.112.251.31:6300/ncobject.jsp?id=9137288153213290331"
--
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log:Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell kranthi123
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Type help() for help on available commands
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Connecting to t3://0.0.0.0:6300 with userid system ...
start_check_state.log-Successfully connected to Admin Server 'devSrv25131' that belongs to domain 'dev'.
--
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log:Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell kranthi123
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Type help() for help on available commands
start_check_state.log-
start_check_state.log-Connecting to t3://0.0.0.0:6300 with userid system ...
start_check_state.log-Successfully connected to Admin Server 'devSrv25131' that belongs to domain 'dev'.
```

I have used split in so many ways and none of them worked

Below are few of them which i have used.

```
split("\n--\n");
split("^\\s");
split("\\n--\\n")
```

none of them have worked

Comment: what about `--`  see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Comment: @ScaryWombat tried that it did not work

Comment: examine what newline char is being used

Comment: What about you post the actual code as an [mcve] -- not just your `split`. The problem may be in some other part of your code

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex: `(?m)^--$\R?`

- [`(?m)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) Enables multiline mode
- [`^`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) Match the beginning of a line
- [`--`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#characters) Match the characters `--`
- [`$`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) Match the end of a line
- [`\R?`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) Optionally match a linebreak

I.e. match a line consisting of nothing but two dash (`-`) characters, including the linebreak ending the line, if present.

As Java code, that is:

```
String[] paragraphs = input.split("(?m)^--$\\R?");
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/TI67Pz) for proof.