# Using the split method to split a text file of music notes that also has line breaks

Tags: java, regex

I am wondering how you can use the split method with this example considering the fact that that there is a line break in the file.

g3,g3,g3,c4-,a3-,g4-,r,r,r,g3,g3,g3,c4-,a3-,a4,g4-,r,r,r,c4,c4,c4,e4,r
g4,r,a4,r,r,b4b,r,a4,f4,r,g4,r,r,g4#,r,g4,d4#,r,g4

I read the Pattern api and tutorials and think it should be like so.

```
line.split("(,\n)");
```

I also tried

```
line.split([,\n]);
```

and

```
line.split("[,\n]");
```

Comment: What happens when you use `.split("[,\n]");`?

Answer (score 1):

lines may separated using `\r` or `\n` both of them, or even some other characters. Since Java 8 you can use `\\R` to represent line separators ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125)). So you could try using

```
String[] arr = yourText.split(",|\\R");
```

Answer (score 0):

[As Pshemo notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869997/8732788), the 3rd option `str.split("[,\n]")` should work assuming the file ends each line with `\n` and not `\r\n`.

Additionally, how you read the file may affect your split argument.

If you are reading the file in with a `BufferedReader`, then going line by line with the [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method will automatically exclude any line-termination characters.

Comment: "*You need to escape the newline twice like \\n*" not quite. `\n` and `\\n` are treated same way in regex engine so `.split("[,\\n]");` is same as `.split("[,\n]");` which OP already tried.