# Java: how to split text by just any possible newline/linebreak characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Im trying to find a regex with whom i can split a certain Text by any possible new character.
I know that i could use `"\\r?\\n"` as regex which would work in almost every case and for almost every platform.

But today i faced a problem where im receiving a String from a Swing component which can't be splitted with this regex like i was hoping.

If the String is printed into the eclipse console i can see that there are linebreaks but probably not using \r\n for linebreaks (dont know yet which special character it is actually, i can see only a the newlines in eclipse console and didn't find a way to display the unicode character for example).

After searching a while for a solution how i can determine these newlines i found another regex which is able to find these line breaks:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(>>String<<<);
```

Now im searching for a way how to combine these regex's or use just one expression to find just any newline.

Anyone a idea?

**I found the reason:**

My Text had some trailing new lines and i was using the wrong String split function. Instead of using

```
text.split("\\r?\\n")
```

i had to use

```
text.split("\\r?\\n", -1)
```

to get **all** lines...

Comment: Use `s.split("\\R")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125/3832970

Comment: For future reference, Swing text components always use a single `\n` as a newline.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Just read its a Java 8 feature but im forced to use 7 :-(

Comment: You have to specify to your matcher to consider your whole string as a single line (?s option), then match all `\s`

Comment: There is its equivalent: `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`. Use it: `s.split("\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]")`