# Java Pdf content to String

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm wondering if is there a way to obtain the content of a pdf file (raw bytes) as a String using Apache PdfBox 2.0.8. What I'm doing is to save the PDDocument object to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then create a new String getting ByteArrayOutputStream's byte array. But if I save the String to a file, the result is a blank pdf. The reason for this is because pdf's stream section bytes are different from a pdf created directly from PdDocument object to a file. After knowing this, I tried to get the ByteArrayOutputStream's character encoding using juniversalchardet, but no luck. So, is there a way to acomplish this?
This is what I have tried so far:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
... //Add page, font, pdPageContentStream and text only to doc object with some latin chars (áéíóú)
doc.save(baos);
```

So, if I create a file using baos object, the pdf file looks as expected, but if I do this:

```
String str = new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

And then create a file using str bytes, the pdf file only shows a blank page.
Hope I was clear enough this time :)

Comment: Please provide your research work which will help us to help you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"the content of a pdf file"*? Do you mean the textual content? Or bitmap images? Or vector images? Or or or...

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/pdfbox-how-to-read-pdf-file-in-java/), just append everything to a `String`.

```
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("your\\path\\file.pdf"))) {
    document.getClass();
    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
        String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind "\\r?\\n"?

Comment: @TomCold it's a regex for splitting the lines - I just took it from the link I provided but you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line