# BE CAREFUL : Splitting a string by newlines can cause bothering bugs

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

Splitting a string by newlines can cause bothering bugs. Please see my answer.

**Original question - XY Problem caused by not being able to see invisible chars in log.**

```
public void DoCommand(String cmd)
{
    String [] words=cmd.split(" ");
    if (words == null)
    {
           Log.e(TAG, "Words null");
           return;
    }
    if (words.length == 0)
    {
         Log.e(TAG, "Words short");
        return;
    }
   String program=words[0].toLowerCase();
   Method method=commandmap.get(program);
    try
    {
        method.invoke(cmdimpl, (Object) words);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException |
            IllegalArgumentException |
            InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "invocation error", e);
        sender.SendError(e);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
   {
        Log.e(TAG, "UNknown cmd", e);
                sender.SendError("unknown command "+program);
   }
    ...
}
```

This is a example of a method in cmdimpl.

```
public void DoHelp(String []args) throws IOException
{
    session.sender.Send(typeConverter.GetBatchInfo("",TypeConverter.FILETYPE.TEXTMSG, WorkerSession.commandmap.keySet().toString()));
}
```

So when I call `DoCommand("help")` it says "unknown command." But when I call `DoCommand("help a")` it works fine.

Any suspicions/suggestions to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

I added some codes to print stack trace but it doesn't work.

```
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "UNknown cmd"+program+".", e);
    sender.SendError("unknown command "+program+"-"+Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
```

`sender.SendError` says

> "unknown command help"

, not

> unknown command help-java.lang.NullPointerException: ...

So it seems that there is something wrong in the `program`.

**EDIT 2**

I suddenly came across one idea that `CR LF/ CR / LF` issue can be a key point.

```
public void ExecuteCommands(String cmds)
{
    workerThread.AddCommand(cmds.split("\n"));  //this \n may be wrong?!
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me how to improve my question or some reasons  after downvoting? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I suggest that you learn some debugging skills. These are among the most important skills to develop as an aspiring computer programming. To help you, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks I 'll read that article.

Comment: Printing "Unknown command" for NullPointerException is not a good idea. You should print "Unknown command" when you know the command is unknown. For NPE print the stack trace at least.

Comment: Error message says that method.invoke(cmdimpl, (Object) words); threw NPE. Purely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much everybody! My actual problem derived from

```
 String.split("\n");
```

. When I changed it to

```
 String.split("\\r?\\n");
```

According to this question [Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454913/8614565),

The problem was gone.

Again thank you for your answers and comments :)

Answer (score 2):

It will return a String[] with one element, which is the original string.

You can test it by:

```
String word="Hello";
String [] words=word.split(" ");
if (words == null) {
  System.out.print("NULL");
} else {
  System.out.println(words.length);
  System.out.println(words[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mike and your example works fine. However I made some mistakes on deciding the title of my question. I clarified my title. Anyway +1 because it gave me partial solution

Comment: When catching an exception, normally we will printout the stack trace for diagnosis , you can do that by e.printStackTrace(), it will give you more information e.g which line got null pointer exception