# How do I fix compiler errors in this program that counts characters, newlines, words of user input and returns them as an array

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program Count.java that counts the characters, newlines, and words in a string input by the user with a return value that is an array of the three counts.

I've written a program that is supposed to store a string entered by the user from the main method as the variable text in the method `public static int[] analyze(String text)` and, then, analyze it with the three integer count variables `wordCount`, `charCount`, and `lineCount`.

```
public class Count { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println("Total number of words: " + arr[0]);
        System.out.println("Total number of characters: " + arr[1]);
        System.out.println("Total number of newlines: " + arr[2]);

    }

    public static int[] analyze(String text) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = in.nextLine();
        int wordCount = 0;
        int charCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 1;
        int[] arr;
        arr = new arr[] {wordCount, charCount, lineCount}; 

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' && text.charAt(i + 1) != ' ') {
                wordCount++;
            }

            if (text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                charCount++;
            }
        }

        if (text.charAt(i) == text.charAt(i)) {
            lineCount++;
        }

        return arr;
    }

}
```

I want it to output the number of characters, newlines, and words of the user's input string. However, when I try to run it, the compiler doesn't recognize my string variable text and array arr. Any suggestion for how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jess,
There is my solution. Also I would suggest you to learn more java core and remember to try to google questions before you ask. Good luck in your journey :)

```
public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = in.nextLine();
        int arr[] = analyze(text);
        System.out.println(arr);
        System.out.println("Total number of words: " + arr[0]);
        System.out.println("Total number of characters: " + arr[1]);
        System.out.println("Total number of newlines: " + arr[2]);

    }

    public static int[] analyze(String text) {
        int[] arr = new int[3];

        // count lines
        String[] lines = text.split("\r\n|\r|\n"); // taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line
        arr[2] = lines.length;

        // count number of words
        arr[0] = countWords(text);

        // count number of characters
        arr[1] = counteCharacters(text);
        return arr;
    }

    static final int OUT = 0;
    static final int IN = 1;

    static int countWords(String str)  // taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-words-in-a-given-string/
    {
        int state = OUT;
        int wc = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length()) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\n'
                    || str.charAt(i) == '\t')
                state = OUT;

            else if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;
                ++wc;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return wc;
    }

    static int count = 0; // taken from https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-count-the-total-number-of-characters-in-a-string

    static int counteCharacters(String text) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) != ' ')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should analyse input data on new string available, because not to store it in one bit `String` object. Another note is to use `Data` object instead of an array; this is more intuitive:

```
public class Count {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a string (empty line to stop): ");

            Data data = analyze(scan);

            System.out.println("Total number of words: " + data.totalWords);
            System.out.println("Total number of characters: " + data.totalCharacters);
            System.out.println("Total number of newlines: " + data.totalNewLines);
        }
    }

    public static Data analyze(Scanner scan) {
        Data data = new Data();

        while (true) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            if (line.isEmpty())
                break;
            else {
                data.totalNewLines++;

                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                    if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
                        data.totalCharacters++;

                data.totalWords += line.split("\\s+").length;
            }
        }

        if (data.totalNewLines > 0)
            data.totalNewLines--;

        return data;
    }

    private static final class Data {

        private int totalCharacters;
        private int totalNewLines;
        private int totalWords;
    }
}
```