# How can I split a string by on empty lines by using split in java?

Tags: java, string, split

1.

```
name Jo Bloggs
birthday 08-07-1900
phone 88884444
address 9001 Chester Crescent, Chatswood, NSW 2057

email michael@fanfare.com.au
name Michael Willianm
birthday 01-4-1950
address 37 Barton Ave, Haberfield, NSW 2045
phone 19876245

name Linda Evans
birthday 22-02-1996
phone 135625
email l.evans@gmail.com
address 119 Gibbes St, Rockdale, NSW 2216
```

2.How can I split these Two strings by empty lines? Here is the code I wrote. string Contains these strings, I want to use a array to store these three strings.

```
String str[] = string.toString().split("\n\r");
```

/*string = the three strings I gave in 1. part */

Comment: Can you edit and post the full code? show how is `string` initialized and it's value.

Comment: I already give the string which equals to the strings in 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the blocks of info are separated by two `\n`s. Hence, you can use `\n\n`.

```
String[] arr = string.split("\n\n");
```