# separate Lines and picking up Each One in new String Variable

Tags: java, string, keyword

String is Like This:

```
String Text="Bank name Some Thing \n Reminder is Some Thing \n Date Some";
```

I want it to be Like this:

```
String T1="Bank Name Some Thing";
String T2="Reminder is Some Thing";
String T3="Date Some";
```

I'm Working with java
I will be thankful to Your Help.

Comment: Thanks for your edit I'm New (Programing&StackOverFlow) .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Comment: answer 2 in this page was

Comment: More Clear then this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` function to split the sentences based on delimiter `\n` and store them in an array. Then by iterating the array, you can access each string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Text="Bank name Some Thing \n Reminder is Some Thing \n Date Some";

    String[] sentences = Text.split("\n");

    for (String s : sentences){
        System.out.println(s.trim());
    }
}
```

Related method's doc page is [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Since there are additional spaces around delimiter, you can use `trim` method to remove them.

If you want to assign the values to different variables as mentioned in your question, you can do it as follows:

```
String T1 = sentences[0].trim();
String T2 = sentences[1].trim();
String T3 = sentences[3].trim();
```

You should also follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of the variables should be `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` instead of `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-)

```
String text =
        "Bank name Some Thing \n Reminder is Some Thing \n Date Some";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine().trim());
}
```

Prints

```
Bank name Some Thing
Reminder is Some Thing
Date Some
```

If you know how many lines you have you can just assign them directly as follows:

```
String T1=scan.nextLine().trim();
String T2=scan.nextLine().trim();
String T3=scan.nextLine().trim();
```