# String print out specific rows

Tags: java

I want specific rows from a String to print out.

String:

```
"
test

 test

 test

 test"
```

I only want the second and the third row.

How should I do this?

Comment: You can get the individual lines by using `theString.split("\\r?\\n")`, this should get you started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a file, use a simple `FileReader` and use `readLine()` method. You can read line by line and take the lines/rows you are interested in.

If you have a simple string containing multiple lines, split by new line character using one of the following options:

```java
String[] values = str.spilt("\\r?\\n|\\r");

# OR

String[] values = str.spilt("\\R");
```

And then take the required values from the array by index.

```java
System.out.println(values[1]+" and "+ values[2]);
```