# Arraylist Output

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an String arraylist with the following content:

```
[0] = "ID: 12"
[1] = "Term: Banana"
[2] = "Definition = yellow fruit"
[3] = "ID: 14"
[4] = "Term: Apple"
[5] = "Definition = green fruit"
[6] = "Description = Beautiful fruit"
[7] = "ID: 16"
[8] = "Term: Melon"
[9] = "Definition = yellow fruit"
```

I only need the output **from ID to the next ID**.

For example:

```
Term: Apple
Definition = green fruit
Description = Beautiful fruit
```

How can I access it without specifying the exact location. I thought of `contains("ID")` until the next `contains("ID")`, I just don't know how to implement it.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: By the looks of it your main problem is that saving your data in that structure (a list of strings) isn't a very good idea. Have you considered creating a custom class that holds all this data (ID, Term and definition) and working with objects of that class instead of just plain strings?

Comment: Maybe you should consider taking the [tour]? (You get the _Informed_ badge after you do.) I see that your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185249/string-print-out-specific-rows) got a few down-votes. May be a good idea to read advice on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

i thing you should use collection objects in the array instead of string as it is.it allows you to collect your desired data in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to print IDs, you can just filter them out by using `String::startsWith`:

```java
List<String> data = Arrays.asList(
    "ID: 12", "Term: Banana", "Definition = yellow fruit",
    "ID: 14", "Term: Apple", "Definition = green fruit", "Description = Beautiful fruit",
    "ID: 16", "Term: Melon", "Definition = yellow fruit"
);

for (String item : data) {
    if (item != null && !item.startsWith("ID:")) {
        System.out.println(item);
    } else { // optionally print empty line to separate items
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```