# Replace new lines and make it all one line in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to split these new lines into one line replace them with commas.

output now=

```
 s = Ar,TB,YY 
    
    0,2022323,02
    
    0,223233,29
```

output I want:

```
s = Ar,TB,YY,0,2022323,02,0,223233,29;
```

I tried using s = s.replaceAll("\n", ","); , didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please, not just s = ....

Comment: I can't see how you could have that string declaration even compile. If it's due to editor wrap, it won't have line separators in it

Comment: try s.replaceAll("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm", "");

Comment: doesnt seem to wokr tinitin

Comment: As @OldProgrammer said, post a minimal reproducible example please.

Comment: While it's a two-step approach, how about `replaceAll("\n+", "\n")`, followed by `replaceAll("\n", ",")`? It's a cost of performance for the simplicity of writing.

Comment: In your example bottom lines also have additional spacing on the left. Are those spaces part of string, or perhaps code indentation?

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 we can use in regex `\R` which represents [line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125) which aside from `\n` can also be `\r`, or `\r\n` pair and more.

So your code can look like

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\R+", ",");
```

- `"\\R"` to represents `\R` in regex
- `+` to match one or more line separator, in case you want to remove more than one empty lines with single comma `,`