# Want to separate long string and add it to list

Tags: java, string, list, split

I have a long string essentially like below,  I want to add each line in the string into the List as its own individual string. In this case for each line, there would be 3 different elements in the List.

```
 String content = "das,fdfd,fdsd,dsds,arer" + "\n" +
                     "abv,dsds,dsa,wew,ewewew" + "\n" +
                     "dfdf,wewes,mds,ojop,nsmcd"

while (content.contains("\n")){
     list = Arrays.asList(content.split("\n"));
    }

   System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the answer? Maybe this could make it more clear.
[Split Java String by New Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line)

```
String content = "das,fdfd,fdsd,dsds,arer" + "\n" +
                     "abv,dsds,dsa,wew,ewewew" + "\n" +
                     "dfdf,wewes,mds,ojop,nsmcd";
if (content.contains("\n")) {
    String[] parts = content.split("\\r?\\n");
    String part1 = parts[0]; 
    String part2 = parts[1];
    String part3 = parts[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a while loop, the `split(String regex)` already returns `String[]`. The `\` character should also be escaped, so `"\n"` becomes `"\\n"`.

```
String content = "das,fdfd,fdsd,dsds,arer" + "\n" +
            "abv,dsds,dsa,wew,ewewew" + "\n" +
            "dfdf,wewes,mds,ojop,nsmcd";

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(content.split("\\n"));
System.out.println(list);
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/DQEEeW).

Comment: Or use a code point integer number instead of an escaped string: `Character.toString( 10 )` instead of `"\\n"`.